# Find the derivative of $\left(\frac{4x+2}{x-2}\right)^5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hey helpful people I have one more question I am stuck on!

$$f(x) = \left(\frac{4x+2}{x-2}\right)^5$$

I know the answer is $$\frac{-50(4x+2)^4}{(x-2)^2(x-2)^4}$$

But I really can't figure out how they got that answer in deriving the whole thing.

Comment: You've been a member for six months, you should really know how to format your questions using MathJax.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm not even sure what you think is the answer because the way you have formatted it doesn't make sense...isn't $(x - 2)^2(x - 2)^4 = (x - 2)^6$???

Answer (score 5):

You should apply chain rule on $f(x)$.

If you let $z=y^5$ and $y=\frac{4x+2}{x-2}$, then chain rule says: 
\begin{align}
\frac{dz}{dx} & =\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}\\ 
f(x) & =\bigg(\frac{4x+2}{x-2}\bigg)^5\\
f'(x) & =5\bigg(\frac{4x+2}{x-2}\bigg)^4\times \frac{(x-2)\times 4-(4x+2)}{(x-2)^2}\\
     & =\frac{5(4x+2)^4(4x-8-4x-2)}{(x-2)^4(x-2)^2}\\
     & =\frac{-50(4x+2)^4}{(x-2)^4(x-2)^2}
\end{align}

And, of course, you could always write $\frac{-50(4x+2)^4}{(x-2)^4(x-2)^2}$ as $\frac{-50(4x+2)^4}{(x-2)^6}$. It is easier to read this way.

Comment: I aligned your equations since they were bleeding into the margin.  Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.